# turn local NodeJS into a online server

Tags: node.js, portforwarding

i'm want to access to my nodejs server from remotly(not in the same network).
I dont know which data i need to apply in this form can some1 help me?

NODEJS PORT:3000
[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll explain the concept first. When a connection is requested to the router from outside (The public IP), the router does not know where to send it, because behind, there could be more than one computer on the network.

What we need to do is tell the router with this rule "If someone sends something in this port, send it to this local computer to this other port".

So, following this concept, we want to take connections from the outside and redirect it to the port of NodeJS on your computer.

The range of the ports for node is from 3000 to 3000, a range of only one element.

So, on local IP, use the local IP of the computer running the NodeJS server. I recommend configuring the network to set up a static IP, so whenever your computer reconnects to the network, does not get a random local IP.

To the Local Start Port and Local End Port use the NodeJS port, which is  3000 as you provide.

On the external IP try leaving the 0.0.0.0, which means "Any IP", so it will not matter which external IP is requested.

And the external port (Start Port and End Port) can be any port which you want. You will need to use the external port when connecting from outside the network, so is recommended to use the same as the local port, just for convenience, which is 3000.

The protocol, depends on what NodeJS does, but I expect that is only needed TCP. If is not the case, you will need to enable both, TCP and UDP.

Answer (score 5):

Just install the `localtunnel` package which will let you access your local server anywhere.

Install Localtunnel globally (requires NodeJS) to make it accessible anywhere:

```
npm install -g localtunnel
```

Start a webserver on some local port (eg http://localhost:8000) and use the command line interface to request a tunnel to your local server:

```
lt --port 8000
```

You will receive a url, for example https://gqgh.localtunnel.me, that you can share with anyone for as long as your local instance of lt remains active. Any requests will be routed to your local service at the specified port

For more info: https://localtunnel.github.io/www/

Hope this helps!

Comment: really nice, have to try it out

Answer (score 1):

Add a DMZ rule inside your router's NAT configuration for the Nodejs local network's IP. 
For example, if NodeJS server is running on a pc with IP 192.168.1.45 then add a DMZ rule for this IP only.